# Lookup item selection in Dynamics

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, lookup, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom lookup on a Dynamics 2011 form.  I also have a javascript library to do a variety of basic validations.  My question is, how do I point to a value in the lookup with javascript?  The below javascript doesn't work...  Please also see image.

Any help appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxz33.png  Lookup

```
if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_contactmethod").getValue() == Jog) 
{

Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("WorkoutDetails").sections.get("Section_Workout").setVisible(true);
  }
else
{
Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("WorkoutDetails").sections.get("Section_Workout").setVisible(false);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_distance").setValue(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve the lookup name in this way:

```js
var methodValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_contactmethod").getValue();
// we check if the lookup is not empty
if (methodValue != null) {
    var methodName = methodValue[0].name;
    if (methodName == "Jog") {
        // your code here
    }
    else {
        // your code here
    }
}
```